# Connectivity issues to mysql database from hybris

Tags: mysql, database, tomcat, sap-commerce-cloud

I was trying to setup hybris but when I tried to initialize from the CLI, the build failed due to Mysql connectivity issue. 
However I am able to connect to mysql database from hybris node using mysql client.

Can any one help me on this ? Could it be some additional privileges required ?

Following is the error thrown at last when performing "ant initialize":

```
 [java] ERROR [main] [DataSourceImpl] error connecting to DataSource having url jdbc:mysql://<mysql-ip>:3306/hybrisdatabase?useConfigs=maxPerformance&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false: Unknown error 1045
```

**Full Error Logs**

```
server:
     [echo] 
     [echo] Configuring server at /ABC/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat
     [echo] Using config set at /ABC/hybris/config/tomcat
     [echo]             
     [echo] copying from /ABC/hybris/config/tomcat to /ABC/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat
     [copy] Copying 9 files to /ABC/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat
     [copy] Copying 3 files to /ABC/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat
     [copy] Copying 2 files to /ABC/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /ABC/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/lib
     [echo] 
     [echo] Embedded server does not seem to be running (no PID found). No restart necessary.
     [echo]                         

initialize:
    [input] skipping input as property tenant has already been set.
     [java] ---------------------------------------------------------------
     [java] Warning: you're using at least one deprecated extension!
     [java] Please note that they may not be available in future releases.
     [java] 
     [java] Deprecated extensions: [liveeditaddon, sapcoreodata]
     [java] ---------------------------------------------------------------
     [java] ---------------------------------------------------------------
     [java] Warning: you're using at least one deprecated extension!
     [java] Please note that they may not be available in future releases.
     [java] 
     [java] Deprecated extensions: [liveeditaddon, sapcoreodata]
     [java] ---------------------------------------------------------------
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.loader.Loader.execute(Loader.java:142)
     [java]     at de.hybris.bootstrap.loader.Loader.main(Loader.java:118)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown error 1045
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.DataSourceImpl.adjustDatabaseInfos(DataSourceImpl.java:647)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.DataSourceImpl.<init>(DataSourceImpl.java:213)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.DataSourceImpl.<init>(DataSourceImpl.java:149)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.DataSourceImplFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceImplFactory.java:51)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant$HybrisDataSourceBuilder.createMasterDataSource(AbstractTenant.java:2869)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant$HybrisDataSourceBuilder.buildMasterDataSourceOnce(AbstractTenant.java:2631)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant$HybrisDataSourceBuilder.build(AbstractTenant.java:2577)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doInitializeSafe(AbstractTenant.java:329)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doInitialize(AbstractTenant.java:308)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartUp(AbstractTenant.java:674)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.assureTenantStarted(Registry.java:648)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateTenant(Registry.java:709)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.setCurrentTenant(Registry.java:556)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateMasterTenantForInit(Registry.java:625)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.util.ClientExecuter.execute(ClientExecuter.java:39)
     [java]     ... 6 more
     [java] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown error 1045
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
     [java]     at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.JDBCConnectionFactory.createRawSQLConnection(JDBCConnectionFactory.java:189)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.JDBCConnectionFactory.createSQLConnection(JDBCConnectionFactory.java:220)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.JDBCConnectionFactory.makeObject(JDBCConnectionFactory.java:109)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:868)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
     [java]     at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.JDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(JDBCConnectionPool.java:113)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.ConnectionErrorCheckingJDBCConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionErrorCheckingJDBCConnectionPool.java:97)
     [java]     at de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.DataSourceImpl.adjustDatabaseInfos(DataSourceImpl.java:629)
     [java]     ... 20 more
     [java] ERROR [main] [DataSourceImpl] error connecting to DataSource having url jdbc:mysql://10.43.4.168:3306/hemdevhybris?useConfigs=maxPerformance&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false: Unknown error 1045
     [java] shutting down hybris registry..

BUILD FAILED
/TK/hybris/bin/platform/build.xml:123: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/ABC/hybris/bin/platform/resources/ant/antmacros.xml:1021: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/ABC/hybris/bin/platform/resources/ant/platformadministration.xml:51: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/ABC/hybris/bin/platform/resources/ant/antmacros.xml:878: Java returned: 1
```

**Hybris local.properties:**

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://<mysql-IP>:3306/hybrisdatabase?useConfigs=maxPerformance&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.username=hybris-user
db.password=*****
db.tableprefix=
mysql.optional.tabledefs=CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
mysql.tabletype=InnoDB
```

**Mysql connectivity from hybris node:**

```
[hybris@****platform]$ mysql -h <mysql-ip> -u hybris-user -p'password'
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2188
Server version: 5.7.20 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MySQL [(none)]> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| hybrisdatabase       |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)


MySQL [(none)]>  SHOW GRANTS FOR 'hybris-user'@'%';
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for hybris-user@%                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'hybris-user'@'%'                       |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `hybrisdatabase`.* TO 'hybris-user'@'%' |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL [(none)]> use hybrisdatabase;
Database changed
MySQL [hybrisdatabase]> show tables;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While creating the Mysql password, please avoid special characters and give the same password properly in Hybris local.properties file.
The "ant" command for Hybris initialization won't work well with MySql passwords with special characters such as  "-, +,#,:.".

Comment: Are you sure that is an answer to the OP's question?

Comment: The special character's used in the mysql  password was indeed the issue.
Initialization was successful when I recreated mysql user without those characters.
Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy the MySQL lib to /hybris/bin/platform/lib/dbdriver/? MySQL lib is not shipped with standard hybris.

Comment: Yes, mysql driver is available: `/ABC/hybris/bin/platform/lib/dbdriver/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar`
Please note that i have updated my description. this is an intermittent connectivity issue. Initialization will be successful sometimes but not always.

Comment: @JeraldSabuM Did you find solution ? I am having same issue, I have driver in the following folder, I am able to access database from workbench but my hybris server is showing cannot connect to unknown database "mydb"

Comment: Please check that a database with the name „mydb“ exists. If not, create it or check then name. Name is the hybrisdatabase part in OP‘s property db.url=jdbc:mysql://<mysql-IP>:3306/hybrisdatabase

Answer (score -1):

Your MySql Server needs to be running, Also you need to put MySQL jar file in the lib folder of the platform.